# Property "loading" does not exist on type "Vue" (NuxtJS)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've been searching for a few hours now but I can't get it figured out. For a NuxtJS project I'm trying to implement a custom loader for in between page loads. However, the documentation is in JS and my project is in TS. My code looks like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({
        data: function () {
            return {
                loading: false
            };
        },
        methods: {
            start(): void {
                this.loading = true;
            },
            finish(): void {
                this.loading = false;
            },
        }
    })
    export default class LoadingBar extends Vue {}
</script>
```

On the "this.loading" in the start() and stop() function, I get the TS error: Property "loading" does not exist on type "Vue". On the frontend it works, the build just won't work because of the TS error.

Any ideas?

I tried to add //ts-ignore but the project's build doesn't accept that. I feel like the way I declare "loading" is off but I've tried moving it/writing it in another way but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured it out. For anyone wanting to know the answer:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        start(): void {
            this.loading = true;
        },
        finish(): void {
            this.loading = false;
        },
    },
});
</script>
```